# Similarity between two sentences using word2vec

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, sentence-similarity

sentence1 = "this is a sentence"
sentence2 = "this is sentence 2"
i want to find similarity between these two sentence . could somebody help me out with a **complete code** of it using **Word2Vec**

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a free code service. We can help you with issues about your code but we won't code for you. If you want someone to write code for you, **pay** a developper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have any word2vec utility as `word2vec`:

```py
import numpy as np

words1 = sentence1.split(' ')
words2 = sentence2.split(' ')

#The meaning of the sentence can be interpreted as the average of its words
sentence1_meaning = word2vec(words1[0])
count = 1
for w in words1[1:]:
    sentence1_meaning = np.add(sentence1_meaning, word2vec(w))
    count += 1
sentence1_meaning /= count

sentence2_meaning = word2vec(words2[0])
count = 1
for w in words2[1:]:
    sentence2_meaning = np.add(sentence2_meaning, word2vec(w))
    count += 1
sentence2_meaning /= count

#Similarity is the cosine between the vectors
similarity = np.dot(sentence1_meaning, sentence2_meaning)/(np.linalg.norm(sentence1_meaning)*np.linalg.norm(sentence2_meaning))
```